# LINQ to entites, query on entity then except from a list (composite key)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I query an entity (InscriptionEcole) with few filters. This entity has a composite key (InscriptionEcoleKey, 7 properties).

In other side, I have a list of key (List).

My goal is to remove from my query the tuples whose key is present in the list.

How can I do that ?

Thank you

InscriptionEcoleKey :

- FkAnneeAnneeScolaire
- FkClDegre
- FkCllEcole
- FkCllFormation
- FkCllVersion
- FkEleNumEleve
- NumIns

Example of query on InscriptionEcole :

```
var ins = DataContext.InscriptionEcole.Where(
    i => i.FkAnneAnnee == "20132014"
      && i.FkCllEcole == "CIFOM"
      && i.Valide == "O"
);
```

Comment: Can you post the structure of `InscriptionEcoleKey` and a basic sample query with the filters

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just filter like so?

```
DataContext.InscriptionEcole.Where(item => !otherList.Contains(item, customComparer));
```

See documentation for Contains [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.100).ASPX)

**UPDATE**

What is needed is a nonequi join:

```
DataContext.InscriptionEcole.Where(ecoleItem => 
    !keys.Any(key => 
        key.FkEleNumEleve == ecoleItem.FkEleNumEleve &&
        key.FkCllEcole == ecoleItem.FkCllEcole && ...));
```

Comment: The types are different. The query is on InscriptionEcole and the list contains InscriptionEcoleKeys !!!

Comment: Ok so just use `Where` instead of `Contains` and check the length of the result

Comment: Can you illustrate your idea @Christian ?

Comment: Well, something like `DataContext.InscriptionEcole.Where(compositeKey => otherList.Where(key => KeysEquals(compositeKey, key)).Length == 0);` which I guess can be written a bit terser like `DataContext.InscriptionEcole.Where(compositeKey => !otherList.Any(key => KeysEquals(compositeKey, key)));` where KeysEquals compares your items in respective collections for equality according to your needs.

Comment: I think what your looking for is a non-equijoin, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882533.aspx) and look at the `NonEquijoin()` example.

Comment: If I understand, "KeysEquals" is a method that returns a bool ? If so, it will not works in LINQ to Entities ! LINQ cannot translate C# functions !!!

Comment: So make the comparison inline in the lambda body instead. What makes two items in the lists equal?

Comment: Two items are equals if all properties of InscriptionEcoleKey are equals with same properties in InscriptionEcole (`InscriptionEcoleKey.FkEleNumEleve == InscriptionEcole.FkEleNumEleve && InscriptionEcoleKey.FkCllEcole == InscriptionEcole.FkCllEcole && ...`).

Comment: Well then you could do: `DataContext.InscriptionEcole.Where(ecoleItem => !keys.Any(key => key.FkEleNumEleve == ecoleItem.FkEleNumEleve && key.FkCllEcole == ecoleItem.FkCllEcole && ...));`

Comment: It does not work : Unable to create a constant value of type "InscriptionEcoleKey". Only primitive types are supported in this context... This is the error that I often encounter when trying to work with composite keys in LINQ to entities...